# Connect 4 - Cant Program Checking If Someone Won

Tags: c++, connect

I've Made A Program That Makes The Whole Game To Work Perfectly, And The Only Thing I Can't Do Is The Checking For A Win.
I've Made The Game In Two Files:
1. Main
2. Functions.
This Is The 'Main' File:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


void getname();
void scoregiving();
void gamestart();
void boardmaking();
void fullgameplay();

int main()
{
    gamestart();
    getname();
    scoregiving();
    fullgameplay();
}
```

This Is The Functions File:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string p1, p2; 
int tu,
    board[6][7],
    colomuns[7],
    makeboard,
    makeboard1,
    scoregive,
    scoregive1,
    input,
    colomunss,
    check,
    check1;

void line()
{
    cout << "|=|=|=|=|=|=|=|\n|";
}
void getname()
{
    cout << "\n\nPlayer, Please Enter Your Name. You'll Be X\n<< ";
    cin >> p1;
    cout << "2nd Player, Please Enter Your Name. You'll Be O\n<< ";
    cin >> p2;
    tu = 1;
}
void gamestart()
{
    cout << "                        (--OOO--OOO---OOO--OOO--)\n";
    cout << "                        |XX========XXX========XX|\n";
    cout << "                       ||CONNECT 4 BY: NETVIZHEN||\n";
    cout << "                        |XX========XXX========XX|\n";
    cout << "                        (--OOO--OOO---OOO--OOO--)";
} 
void boardmaking()
{ 
    cout << "\n\nBoard:\n";
    cout << "\n 0 1 2 3 4 5 6\n";
    line();
    for (makeboard = 0; makeboard <= 5; makeboard ++)
        for (makeboard1 = 0; makeboard1 <= 6; makeboard1++)
        {
            if (board[makeboard][makeboard1] == 0)
            {
                cout << " |";
            }
            else if (board[makeboard][makeboard1] == 1)
            {
                cout << "X|";
            }
            else if (board[makeboard][makeboard1] == 2)
            {
                cout << "O|";
            }
            if (makeboard1 == 6)
            {
                cout << "\n";
                line();
            }
        }
}
void scoregiving()
{
    for (scoregive = 0 ; scoregive < 6 ; scoregive++)
      for (scoregive1 = 0 ; scoregive1 < 7 ; scoregive1++)
              board[scoregive][scoregive1] = 0;
    for (colomunss = 0; colomunss <= 6; colomunss++)
        colomuns[colomunss] = 0;
}
void wincheck()
{
    for (check = 0; check <=5; check++)
        for (check1 = 0; check1 <= 6; check1++)
            if (board[check][check1] == tu)
                if (board[check - 1][check1] == tu && board[check - 2][check1] ==  tu && board[check - 3][check1] == tu && board[check][check1] == tu)
                    cout << "ggh";
}
void putin()
{
    cout << "\n<< ";
    cin >> input;
    if (input >= 7)
        cout << "\nThis Location Is Outside The Board. Please Retry.";
    else if (colomuns[input] > 5 )
    cout << "\nThis Column Is Full. Please Retry.";
    else
    {
        board[5-colomuns[input]][input] = tu;
        colomuns[input]++;
        wincheck();
        if (tu == 2)
            tu--;
        else if (tu == 1)
            tu++;
    }
} 
void fullgameplay()
{
    while(true)
    {
        boardmaking();
        putin();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously mentioned you would want to check each direction either in 8 for loops or with boolean values to check each time.

```
bool n = true;
bool ne = true;
bool e = true;
bool se = true;
bool s = true;
bool sw = true;
bool w = true;
bool nw = true;

for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++)
{
  if (board[x + count][y] != tu)
  {
    e = false;
  }

  if (board[x + count][y + count] != tu)
  {
    ne = false; 
  }
//continue for each direction.

  if(n == true || ne == true || e == true //and so on)
  {
    //player wins
  }
}
```

This is the main concept that could be used though obviously some changes will have to be made to fit your code.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force: from each position, traverse in the eight different directions as long as the position is in the board, not empty and the same as the original position.  If you reach 4, then the player in the original position is the winner.

Since you should do it after each play, at most one player can have a connect 4.

You can make an array of the 8 directions to use the needed deltas for x and y for each direction.